# Replacing the nth white by an asterisk in GBQ

Tags: sql, regex, string, google-bigquery

`REGEXP_REPLACE("My dog is funny and happy", r"(\S+ \S+ \S+)", r"*")` This is my SQL for achieving this. My output should look something like this = My dog is funny *and happy

When I try the above query it removes the first few words. How do I work this out?

Comment: It works but for "My dog is funny and happy but that cat over there is very cunning" this longer sentence. "The output is My dog is funny * and happy but that * cat over there is * very cunning", I just want "My dog is funny * and happy but that cat over there is very cunning" this. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a backreference:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE("My dog is funny and happy", r"^((?:\S+\s+){4})", r"\1*")
REGEXP_REPLACE("My dog is funny and happy", r"^(?:\S+\s+){4}", r"\0*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fOg3r9/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:\S+\s+){4})` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement will refer to this group value): four occurrences of one or more non-whitespaces followed with one or more whitespaces.

`\0` refers to the whole match value.

See the `regexp_replace` [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace):

> `REGEXP_REPLACE(value, regexp, replacement)`
>
> Returns a `STRING` where all substrings of `value` that match regular
> expression `regexp` are replaced with `replacement`.
>
> You can use backslashed-escaped digits (\1 to \9) within the
> `replacement` argument to insert text matching the corresponding
> parenthesized group in the `regexp` pattern. Use \0 to refer to the
> entire matching text.